# ¿Como pasar una variable de Javascript a asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

Necesito enviar una imagen que está en base 64, a la base de datos SQL server como puedo capturar la variable que tiene los datos en base 64 si esta se encuentra en una variable de  Javascript para poder enviarlos desde asp.net C#.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function readFile(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var filePreview = document.createElement('img');
            filePreview.id = 'file-preview';
            // e.target.result contiene los datos base64 de la imagen cargada
            filePreview.src = e.target.result;
            console.log(e.target.result);

            var previewZone = document.getElementById('file-preview-zone');
            previewZone.appendChild(filePreview);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

var fileUpload = document.getElementById('file-upload');

fileUpload.onchange = function (e) {
    readFile(e.srcElement);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Básicamente tienes que hacer una petición AJAX a tu backend. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gOMxLuevY48

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes enviarla por medio de una llamada `ajax` por medio de `jquery`, con el `$.ajax`, invocando un `WebMethod` definido en el codigo de la pagina

[Calling ASP.Net WebMethod using jQuery AJAX](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx)

la dea es usar

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CS.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
        data: '{name: "' + $("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
```

enviando el base64 en el `data` para que lo recibas en el servidor

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetCurrentTime(string name)
{
    return "Hello " + name + Environment.NewLine + "The Current Time is: "
        + DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

con un metodo `public` decorado con el atributo `[WebMethod]`

Como observaras lo que envias desde el cliente javascript es un `json` alli es donde pondras el `base64`

Comment: **data: '{name: "' + $("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }'**  Esta Parte del codigo no la entiendo Amigo

Comment: esa parte la copie del ejemplo del articulo, ese es el json que menciono, alli es donde pondrias el e.target.result, algo como ser { fielContent: base64 }, pero se supone que el valor de e.target.result lo deberias poner en alguna variable para poder accederla por fuera de  readFile()

Comment: Hola una pregunta en el  **return** del metodo en mi caso como  seria, yo pensaría algo como esto ** ToString()** solamente?

Comment: como en tu caso solo quieres enviar desde javascript al servidor ese metodo podrias definirlo como "void" asi no devuelves nada como respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias,  ya para finalizar En el **data** de la función, me dices que **deberias poner en alguna variable para poder accederla por fuera de readFile()** esa variable con el valor del e.target.result la declaro en el aspx.cs cierto ? o estoy equivocado ?

Comment: No es codigo javascript, ejecuta en el cliente. No se donde defines el codigo cliente, pero quizas vaya en el aspx junto al html

Comment: En esta misma  function readFile coloco el $.ajax o hago una aparte ? No me esta haciendo el envió

Comment: si se podria hacer dentro de readFile(), podrias con el developer analizar el js y ver si hay algun mensaje en la consola de algun error en javascript